# Integrate Slider Into WordPress Theme

Tags: php, wordpress, slider, wordpress-theming

My website is http://www.edumuffin.com/ (hompage)

This website is built using Listify WordPress theme.

I want to have a slider in the homepage for which I am using the plugin Slider Revolution. The thing is I want the slider to be in place of the hero image, with the search on top.
The theme has multiple page templates; **the homepage uses the template as below:**

```html
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Page: Home
 *
 * @package Listify
 */

if ( ! listify_has_integration( 'wp-job-manager' ) ) {
 return locate_template( array( 'page.php' ), true );
}

get_header(); ?>

 <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

  <?php $style = get_post()->hero_style; ?>

  <?php if ( 'none' !== $style ) : ?>

   <?php if ( in_array( $style, array( 'image', 'video' ) ) ) : ?>

   <div <?php echo apply_filters( 'listify_cover', 'homepage-cover page-cover entry-cover entry-cover--home entry-cover--' . get_theme_mod( 'home-hero-overlay-style', 'default' ), array( 'size' => 'full' ) ); ?>>
    <div class="cover-wrapper container">
     <?php
      the_widget(
       'Listify_Widget_Search_Listings',
       apply_filters( 'listify_widget_search_listings_default', array(
        'title' => get_the_title(),
        'description' => strip_shortcodes( get_the_content() )
       ) ),
       array(
        'before_widget' => '<div class="listify_widget_search_listings">',
        'after_widget'  => '</div>',
        'before_title'  => '<div class="home-widget-section-title"><h1 class="home-widget-title">',
        'after_title'   => '</h1></div>',
        'widget_id'     => 'search-12391'
       )
      );
     ?>
    </div>

    <?php
     if ( 'video' == $style ) :
      wp_reset_query();

      add_filter( 'wp_video_shortcode_library', '__return_false' );
      
      the_content();

      remove_filter( 'wp_video_shortcode_library', '__return_false' );
     endif;
    ?>
   </div>

   <?php else : ?>

    <div class="homepage-cover has-map">
     <?php
      do_action( 'listify_output_map' );

      if ( ! is_active_widget( false, false, 'listify_widget_map_listings', true ) ) {
       do_action( 'listify_output_results' );
      }
     ?>
    </div>

   <?php endif; ?>

  <?php endif; ?>

  <?php do_action( 'listify_page_before' ); ?>

  <div class="container homepage-hero-style-<?php echo $style; ?>">

   <?php if ( listify_has_integration( 'woocommerce' ) ) : ?>
    <?php wc_print_notices(); ?>
   <?php endif; ?>

   <?php
    if ( is_active_sidebar( 'widget-area-home' ) ) :
     dynamic_sidebar( 'widget-area-home' );
    else :
     $defaults = array(
      'before_widget' => '<aside class="home-widget">',
      'after_widget'  => '</aside>',
      'before_title'  => '<div class="home-widget-section-title"><h3 class="home-widget-title">',
      'after_title'   => '</h3></div>',
      'widget_id'     => ''
     );

     the_Widget(
      'Listify_Widget_Recent_Listings',
      array(
       'title' => __( 'Recent  Listings', 'listify' ),
       'description' => __( 'Take a look at what\'s been recently added.', 'listify' ),
       'limit' => 6,
       'featured' => 0
      ),
      $defaults
     );
    endif;
   ?>

  </div>

 <?php endwhile; ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

There is a template provided which can be used to add a slider using a shortcode. The shortcode I am using is [rev_slider alias="slider1"]. Check the page here http://www.edumuffin.com/test-page/

**The template which this page uses is as below:**

```html
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Page: Home (Slider 2)
 *
 * @package Listify
 */

if ( ! listify_has_integration( 'wp-job-manager' ) ) {
 return locate_template( array( 'page.php' ), true );
}

get_header(); ?>

 <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

  <?php the_content(); ?>

  <?php do_action( 'listify_page_before' ); ?>

  <div class="container">

   <?php if ( listify_has_integration( 'woocommerce' ) ) : ?>
    <?php wc_print_notices(); ?>
   <?php endif; ?>

   <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'widget-area-page-' . get_the_ID() ); ?>

  </div>

 <?php endwhile; ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Though I can still add widgets to this page to have content as in my website homepage, but the search will still not appear.

I want to have the slider as it appears in test-page on my homepage, with the search intact on top of the slider.

Revolution slider provides the following code for embedding the slider:

**Advanced Embeding**
From the theme html use:

```html
<?php putRevSlider( 'slider1' ); ?>
```

To add the slider only to homepage use:

```html
<?php putRevSlider('slider1', 'homepage'); ?>
```

To add the slider on specific pages or posts use:

```html
<?php putRevSlider('slider1', '2,10'); ?>
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.